# How to hide actual ClientId from swagger while doing AzureAd token authentication in WebAPI

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, swagger-ui, webapi, azure-authentication

I have configured AzureAd token authentication for my webAPI but in swagger page its showing the actual clientId value but I don't want to show the actual value of ClientId to the end user. That means in the code I can hardcode but in the swagger page I want to show some dummy value, how that can be done?
In the clientId textbox, I want to pass any random value like 'swaggerClient'

[image]

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(op =>
            {
                    var openApi = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                        {
                            AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                            {
                                AuthorizationUrl = "https://abcde.com",
                                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                {
                                    { Scope, "mvc1"}
                                },
                                TokenUrl = "https://abcde.com/token"
                            }
                        },
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                        Name = "Authorization",
                        Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2
                    };

                    op.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                                {
                                    {
                                          new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                                          {
                                              Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                              {
                                                  Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                                  Id = "oauth2"
                                              }
                                          },
                                         new string[] {}
                                    }
                                });

                    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", openApi);
                    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
                
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Client_id is not hided as that it is not a secret as  OAuth specification [RFC 6749 - The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-2.2)  indicates  and it is exposed to the resource owner and must be used along with client secret for client authentication and secret is hided anyway.

Please check if the parameter can be hidden by using  `SchemaFilter`  with `IgnoreDataMember`  something like [C# ASP.NET : Hide model properties from Swagger doc - DEV Community](https://dev.to/kenakamu/c-aspnet-hide-model-properties-from-swagger-doc-626)

- GET the client id from getter and setter class

  ```
  [IgnoreDataMember]
   public string ClientId { set; get; }
  ```
- use ISchemaFilter to control it. Add new class.

  ```
    using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
    using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

   namespace swaggertest
    {
     public class MySwaggerSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
         {
       public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
       {
           if (schema?.Properties == null)
           {
               return;
           }

           var ignoreDataMemberProperties = context.Type.GetProperties()
               .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<IgnoreDataMemberAttribute>() != null);

           foreach (var ignoreDataMemberProperty in ignoreDataMemberProperties)
           {
               var propertyToHide = schema.Properties.Keys
                   .SingleOrDefault(x => x.ToLower() == ignoreDataMemberProperty.Name.ToLower());

               if (propertyToHide != null)
               {
                   schema.Properties.Remove(propertyToHide);
               }
           }
       }
     }
  }
  ```
- And then specifying in the start up

  ```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {

   services.AddControllers();
   services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
   {
       c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "swaggertest", Version = "v1" });
       c.SchemaFilter<MySwaggerSchemaFilter>();
   });
   ...
  }
  ```

Or by `changing the DOM` properties as suggested by [kievu in github issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5178#issuecomment-463557244)

You can raise a azure [**support request**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) or [swagger support](https://swagger.io/support/)  regarding the same.

**References:**

1. [Testing Azure AD-protected APIs, part 1: Swagger UI - Joonas W's
   blog](https://joonasw.net/view/testing-azure-ad-protected-apis-part-1-swagger-ui)
2. [How To Swagger Hide API Or Route Method – Guidelines |TheCodeBuzz](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/swagger-show-hide-api-action-method-openapi/)